# Python program addition error

Tags: python

```
print ("This is a puzzle favored by Einstein. You will be asked to enter a three digit number, where the hundred's digit differs from the one's digit by at least two. The procedure will always yield 1089")
num = input("Give me a number which satisfies the rule of the game: ")
revnum = ((num[2]) + (num[1]) + (num[0]))
print("For the number: "+num+" the reverse number is: "+ revnum)
if num > revnum:
    print("The difference between ", num, "and ", revnum, "is ", int(num)-int(revnum))
else:
    print("The difference between ",revnum+" and ",num+" is ",int(revnum)-int(num))
if revnum > num:
    diff = str(float(revnum)-float(num))
else:
    diff = str(float(num)-float(revnum))
revdiff = (diff[2]+ diff[1]+diff[0])
print ("The reverse difference is: "+revdiff)
print ("The sum of: ",diff," and reversed difference is ",(diff + revdiff))
```

Hello guys, when I run this program the last line should give me 1089 regardless of what the user inputs but I get a strange number instead... Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What number DO you get?

Comment: If the difference is 198, the sum is 198.0891. I think its a problem with the string but not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: Replace `float` with `int`.

Comment: Yes, suddenly bringing floats into it introduces potential inexactitude (as you are seeing) for no benefit.  
You might also consider using absolute value (abs()) so that you don't have to care whether the smaller number comes first or not.

Comment: @devull then I get 198891 and not the addition of the two sums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You converted the number `diff` and `revdiff` to strings, which makes `diff + revdiff` string concatenation. You need to convert them back to numbers in the last line to make `+` right. Change:

```
diff + revdiff
```

to:

```
int(diff)+int(revdiff)
```

and code like `float(revnum)` needs to be `int(revnum)` because when converting a string to an int e.g. `int(diff)`, `diff` should not be a string representing a float e.g. `"1.0"`.

Comment: There's a very good reason it's being converted to a string: the string is then indexed to retrieve individual digits.

Comment: But when I do that I get this error: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @zhangxaochen then this error occurs:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @user3393463 I mean, `diff = str(int(revnum)-int(num))` is necessary, but in the last line, `diff + revdiff` should be `int(diff) + int(revdiff)`